# why would Spring Sql loose track of H2DB Exceptions and raise a NoClassDefFound Exception

Tags: java, spring, h2

I am using a Mysql database in production and an embedded H2 data base for Junit testing.
Access to my database in my Dao code classes is done via

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate userDBJdbcTemplate;
```

Actual calls to database are done via `userDBJdbcTemplate.update(...)` calls.

My Junit test cases subclass an abstract class with appropriate profile that autowire properly the H2 base

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ... })
@ActiveProfiles({"database-test"})
public abstract class H2DBTests {
```

This works all fine but when I do a shitty coding work in the Sql querys or statements, `userDBJdbcTemplate.update(...)` will fail but the initial cause of the exception (like forgetting to to a ps.setxxx for a column in some cases for example...) is lost in the process. I end up with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with information loss.

More precisely, the cause exception is raised in `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` class. For example here a

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#5" is not set
```

exception is rightly raised which is lost somewhere in this call later on in the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` class :

```
throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("PreparedStatementCallback", sql, ex);
```

When I am back in my code, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException` with no reference at all to the missing argument in the ps setup.

Comment: `QueryTimeoutException` is in the `spring-tx-X.X.X.jar` file. It would seem that you're missing that jar file in your classpath.

Comment: Thxs. Am I missing one of the dependency from maven? Currently having as maven dependency spring-core, spring-context, spring-jdbc, spring-test

Comment: What is strange is that the Query Time out exception has nothing to do with the real org.h2 exception which is really raised. It must be set up somewhere in the spring sql exception translation process which I have problem to follow precisely...

Comment: Maven names and jar file names are the same, so add maven dependency `spring-tx`. Your actual exception may not map to a `QueryTimeoutException`, but the spring sql exception translation code may still need the class to be present, so add the dependency and see if that makes everything work correctly.

Comment: FYI: `spring-jdbc` should have pulled in `spring-tx` for you. At least it does in 4.2.6, according to my Gradle build script.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Spring-tx jar is actually present in the class paht but with an older release (3.0.6) even after spring test and spring jdbc dependencies upgraded to 4.2.6. I will clean up my dependencies and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas led to the right reason : Spring project dependencies are wrongly configured. The spring-tx module that is needed for correct translation of exception was in a 3.0.6 release where as my spring-core and spring-jdbc were on 4.2.6 release.

Another part of the project is using spring ldap with 1.3.2 release which was pulling spring-tx 3.0.6. In order to preserve use of 1.3.2 spring ldap release, the right solution is to add an exclusion for spring-tx in the spring-ldap part.

Here is the modified version of the pom.xml that makes everything work :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.ldap-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```